# terms of use at login

Tags: 7, users

The user has to agree to a terms of use at EACH login, not just at registration. 
What is the easiest way to do this?

Right now, I have a login page with only a login block on it (asking for username and password); once logged in the users are sent to the homepage. I need a pop up with terms of usage to appear after the login. The user accepts the 'terms of use' and are then directed to homepage, or are logged out.

There are several good modules that do what I want but only at registration, not for EACH login.

Comment: Why would you like to have terms of use confirmed at each login ?

Comment: I ended up using the module "Legal".

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan).  There's [an example](http://drupal.org/node/880904) on the project homepage that nearly matches your use case.

Comment: No, but good try, the problem is the user is logged in then redirected to another page.  Nothing prevents the user from then manually changing the URL once at the redirected to page and going anywhere they like (they are legally logged in).  Users HAVE to approve the terms of use page or are logged out.  I think the only way to solve the problem is to override the login function (I'll look for a hook) and include a Boolean, "license_approved".  In the method a pop up will be called and the "license_approved" will be set there.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can user [Terms Of Use](http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use) module for integration.

Though this module provides terms of use checkbox at only registration page, But you can achieve the same for login also.

Just overview the code and you can use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

In this module check **terms_of_use_form_user_register_form_alter()** function. You can use this code and implement your own **terms_of_user_from_user_login_form_alter()** function.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Legal](http://drupal.org/project/legal) module, very useful

> Displays your Terms & Conditions to users who want to register, and requires that they accept the T&C before their registration is accepted.
>
> If T&Cs are changed users with an existing account will be asked to accept the new version, and will not be able to log in until they have.